# accessing word variable or content control from outlook vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to access from Outlook VBA, either a variable or content control ID that I've created in a word Macro.

Basically I am trying to get set a text field equal to a string variable and load this variable to a message box in outlook.

From outlook, I have the code that creates a word object, and opens the active document, but I'm confused as to accessing the variables. I've tried making the variable in word VBA a public variable with no luck.

Current code to access the variable from outlook:

```
Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") 
Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Owner\Desktop\Job.docx") 
oWordApp.Visible = True 
MsgBox(oWordApp.testtest)
```

Comment: Can you post some code explaining how you are calling the function in Outlook? Please provide a [mcve], which is explained in the [help].

Comment: You need to show us the code you have, point out the line(s) that give a problem, describe what you expect them to do and what they actually do do - with an example of the result, if possible. Please use the [edit] link to add this information to your question - don't put it in a Comment.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs I've added the referencing code above

Comment: @CindyMeister I referenced the code above, I added in what I have in Outlook vba, trying to show in a message box the string variable testtest, which is also just a string with the text "test"

Comment: You may be able to set a reference to the project within the VBE.. `Tools > References`.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but it's still not clear what the problem is. What do you mean by "the variables"?

Comment: You're too fast :-) You mean you want to search text in the document? Such as the "Find" does in the UI?

Comment: @CindyMeister I am trying to, in an outlook appointment body display the text associated with the testtest variable located in my word macro. So testest = “hi” for example. I want to access this variable from within outlook and display the text in a new appointment body.

Comment: Do you mean *Document Variables* - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/document-variables-property-word ?

Comment: Robert, please show us more code. You don't show us the declaration of testtest, for example, or how it's populated. We need something we can test with. You way "display the text in a new appointment body" BUT you're automating Word and opening a document. Is this document to become the appointment body? So you want to write the string data testtest contains to the Word document? How are you identifying the target where the data should be written? Are you using a bookmark? A content control? Something else? Please be specific.

Comment: Do you mean a variable created by a Word VBA procedure?  E.g. Your Word Doc has `Dim MyVariable As Long: Long = 25` and you want to return the value of `MyVariable`?  In which case your example should be `"C:\Owner\Desktop\Job.docm")` (as it would need to be a macro enabled document).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a look at the ContentControl help file you can pull back the text from the content control using its Tag property.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim oWordApp As Object
    Dim oWordDoc As Object

    Dim oContent As Variant
    Dim oCC As Variant

    Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Open("S:\DB_Development_DBC\Test\MyNewDoc.docm")
    oWordApp.Visible = True


    Set oContent = oWordDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("MyCalendarTag")
    If oContent.Count <> 0 Then
        For Each oCC In oContent
            MsgBox oCC.PlaceholderText & vbCr & oCC.Range.Text
        Next oCC
    End If

End Sub
```

The code above displayed *Click here to enter a date.* as the `PlaceHolderText` value and *01/01/2007* as the `Range.Text` value.  So no need to add separate functions; just reference the content control directly.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg605189(v=office.14).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/working-with-content-controls

**Edit**
As an example of returning value from multiple controls in one function:

```
Public Sub Example()

    Dim MySevenTags As Variant
    Dim x As Long

    MySevenTags = Array("Tag1", "Tag2", "Tag3", "Tag4", "Tag5", "Tag6", "Tag7")

    For x = LBound(MySevenTags) To UBound(MySevenTags)
        MsgBox ReturnFromWordContent(CStr(MySevenTags(x))), vbOKOnly
    Next x

End Sub

Public Function ReturnFromWordContent(TagID As String) As Variant

    Dim oWordApp As Object
    Dim oWordDoc As Object

    Dim oContent As Variant
    Dim oCC As Variant

    Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Open("S:\DB_Development_DBC\Test\MyNewDoc.docm")
    oWordApp.Visible = True

    Set oContent = oWordDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag(TagID)

    'I've made this next bit up.
    'No idea how to get the type of control, or how to return the values.
    Select Case oContent.Type
        Case "calendar"
            ReturnFromWordContent = oContent.Range.Date
        Case "textbox"
            ReturnFromWordContent = oContent.Range.Text
        Case Else
            'Return some default value such as Null which
            'won't work in this case as it's returning to a messagebox
            'but you get the picture.
    End Select

'    If oContent.Count <> 0 Then
'        For Each oCC In oContent
'            MsgBox oCC.PlaceholderText & vbCr & oCC.Range.Text
'        Next oCC
'    End If

End Function
```

Comment: I am needing to access about 7 'ByTag' IDs though. I have that exact code for the IF loop, but could you reference all 7 tag ID's under 1 function? Since the function starts with Public testtest() As string, aren't you setting the entire function equal to the variable testtest? If you declared other variables within the function, how would you access those directly? I am using  oWordApp.Run("testtest") at the moment to access the variable testtest located in the testtest() function. Is there a way to access different variables within the function? for instance, testtest.variable2 and so on

Comment: You could pass the Tag value to the procedure, use a select case on the control type so it looks for the correct property dependent on the type and then returns the values.  I'll write some semi-pseudo code into my answer to show what I mean - haven't got time at the moment to make sure I get the correct syntax.

Comment: The code in my edit is what you need.  It passes seven tags to the procedure.  The `Select Case` block will need updating to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

"I've tried making the variable in word VBA a public variable with no luck."

Declare your macro "testtest" as a function with the return value of your variable.

```
Public Function testtest() As String

    dim myVariabel as String

    myVariable = "test"

    ' return value 
    testtest = myVariable

End Function
```

Best regards

Comment: And to call it from outlook, would it be oWordApp.testtest?

Comment: No, in your code it would be `MsgBox oWordApp.Run("TestTest")`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook

Basically what I was trying to do was set a string variable equal to a contentcontrol ID in word, and then access this variable from Outlook. What I am doing now is setting the Subject of a new appointment in Outlook equal to the variable in my word macro that holds the text of a particular content control ID. I will post my code here later to see if there is an easier way to do it, but I've created 7 separate functions to hold each content control variable.

Comment: At the moment, everything works with 7 separate functions, but would there be a way to access multiple variables from one function?

for instance MsgBox oWordApp.Run(TestTest.variable5)